# Is it ethical to earn reputation by copying contents from own/others' duplicates?

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates

Suppose, question B is identified as duplicate of question A. Now user X answers B. It might be voted &/or accepted by OP of question B.
If this is done knowing full well that post A has an answer already.

Is it fair practice to be followed by all?

Comment: As soon as question gets closed, new answers can't be posted. However existing answers can be upvoted and accepted and the user posted answer will get reputation points for it. Btw, if you find new answer sounds duplicate or identical to the existing answer, you may flag for deletion.

Comment: I think its gaming the system for reputation.

Comment: Are you talking about [this today's post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22432/1049)?  The answerer had already posted everything in duplicate Qn. Yet the user posted the same answer as non-wiki.

Comment: @iammilind  yes that's the post

Comment: @iammilind It is not possible to remember each and every answer you have posted when you have given 400 + answers..You can ask him to delete if he is trying to earn rep from it.

Comment: @NogShine, you should not defend in this case that user. Reasonably before the answer was posted, it was already linked by me as a duplicate. The user should have seen the link & possibly might have copied contents from own Qn & posted as an answer. It's probably legal, as even I could have copied that content to form an answer. But ethical or not?.

Comment: Do you think it is defending? Uf.. @iammilind Do whatever you want..

Comment: @iammilind and moonstar I don't agree they are duplicates. I would select it as leave open in the reviews. It was mod hammered. Remember [what you said](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41433439#41433439)?

Comment: @NogShine re: your example and link about what i said, this seems to be an exception. because the same user is involved and the same content.

Comment: @moonstar2001 First I thought he posted answer to the duplicate question and answered this original also. It turns out that he asked the question and didn't answer the original. Also, the questions differ in some manner. So, I don't thing they are not duplicates.

Comment: Now, the title and body are asking differently, How to answer these questions? @moonstar2001

Comment: Well the answer is almost completely a CNP from answerer's one of own Qs. And, the reason "why" is copied from (or took hint from) Pandya's answer which cites an Upanishad. But weird thing is that although he thinks that is the answer but he has not selected Pandya's answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you are discussing about following post:
[does the soul go somewhere when we deep sleep?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22432/1049)

This Qn is already answered in the linked duplicate within the Qn itself. If you see the [original Qn](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15044/1049) and the [new answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22434/1049), they are mostly identical with respect to the scripture.

As soon as I saw the Qn, I linked with the duplicate. Despite that, the user decided to post an answer after **45 minutes**!

This special scenario is already discussed in the main meta:
[If another question/answer *perfectly* answers a question (but the question is quite different), is it appropriate to answer with just a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174138/163449)

> In a scenario where the questions aren't the same, but the new (potentially duplicate) question is solidly answered by the original question (and/or its answers), it would be appropriate to close as a duplicate. ...

Ethically if there is a repeat value in an answer, then it should be wiki-fied as soon as it's posted to disallow new reputation.

Since, here the answering user is also a moderator, we can't expect any action. But in case of the normal users, we should flag such posts.

> > *BG 3.21 - Whatever a superior person does, another person does that very thing! Whatever he upholds as authority, an ordinary person follows that*.

Comment: "Since, here the answering user is also a moderator, we can't expect any action. But in case of the normal users, we should flag such posts." - that is truly unfortunate.

Comment: Duplicate answers are not allowed. The user copied from his question and not from his answer. So, there is a difference. Copying from a question is okay I guess.

Comment: @NogShine, you may read the linked meta post. It clearly says in heading as well as accepted answer: *"If another **question/answer** perfectly answers a question ..."*. There are few Qn-s which are closed in this site as well, where the Qn itself was answering another Qn. The answerer being a Mod, is well aware of this fact. Just imagine, if these 2 Qn-s are merged then how will the new answer look? It will be mostly a copy of the Qn. :-) They are not merged because the new Qn provides a good link to the old post. Will it be OK, if everyone starts this rep farming, instead of linking as dupe?

Comment: First of all. Are they exact duplicates to be closed and merged? I suggest you to read the answer by rachel which has the quote from a SO employee which has more votes. It says "We should not be closing duplicates "whether you should close non-duplicate questions as duplicates just because they have the same answer, no you should not. ". Questions make questions duplicate not answers. Another [post to read](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2760/48608). If the questions are different, then they should be closed.

Comment: The example mentioned in your answer is complex and there is no exact *rule* (although guidelines may be there) and this should be done on discretion of community. For example, some users are happy with closing as duplicates (including myself) while others won't be happy in closing them as duplicates. So, i think best solution is to leave it as it is in current state.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, the rule of thumb can be -- what if everyone does that? I probably raise max number of dupe votes. What if I start copying those contents, slightly altering them and posting them as answers, mostly without credits to the other posts. That's not illegal, But do we want to see the community doing such? For this particular post, we can also virtually "simulate" a merge of those 2 Qn-s, since they are duplicates. Now original Qn and the new answer, will look funnily similar! The bigger problem is that, when a Mod does, it sets an example for others to follow.

Comment: @iammilind Issue here is "There is no single opinion on whether these two posts are duplicates". for example, if questions are entirely different and answers are same, it can be allowed. See [“Close as duplicate” - what if only the answer is a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74080/375276). Let;s see in 3 cases 1) if questions are exactly duplicate (say paraphrased), we can close them and this is simplest case. 2) if questions are entirely different but  produce same answer, then not fine to close. Above linked question says it. (1/2)

Comment: 3) The other case is : "What is relationship between Rama and Lakshmana?" and "How is Rama brother of Lakshmana?". Closing them needs discretion. Some users agree with closing while others won't. This is exactly what is the case here.  if you are fine with closing, then answering the text from question seems unethical for you. But i think objectively this can't be solved as there are no exact rules. (2/2)

Comment: @TheDestroyer The rules are clear here. If a question is asked in two different ways and have the same answer, then they are not duplicates. I have linked a meta post in above comments which cites the same meta you linked. As there is a problem with closing duplicates, it is not right to say this user is rep farming, they are against the rules  and someone said they should leave community (with caps) etc., . So, one of the moderators should address this one.

Comment: @NogShine Can you show me exact case on meta SE which is presented here? Moreover, see link in milind's answer. It says it can be done. So, there's no single rule on this issue. And where did i say the user is rep farming? As per my discretion, i would avoid answering it.

Comment: @TheDestroyer It is not you. Others are saying about rep farming. I'm talking about [this comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/is-it-ethical-to-earn-reputation-by-copying-contents-from-own-others-duplicates/1026?noredirect=1#comment3936_1026) . I quoted an answer from linked post which says different questions can not be closed. It has words of a SE employee and linked to a movies meta post which cited "Close as duplicate” - what if only the answer is a duplicate?"

Comment: @NogShine It is subjective. Since questions here are not completely different. They are similar. Again, opinion varies with person to person.

Comment: It is not opinions @TheDestroyer .  There are meta posts whether or not to close them. Isn't it? This is not a POB. They are duplicates. They are not 'exact duplicates' The original asks "Why does the Jiva reside" and the duplicate asks "Does the Jiva leave or reside". So, they are different. The original question is specific. See the passages at the end.

Comment: @NogShine Ok. you are not getting my point. leave it.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Will you close "Is Ganga sacred" as a duplicate of  "Why is  Ganga sacred" given that the latter one gives why Ganga is sacred and there is no answer to it and just a question? It is the same scenario here. Hope you understand now and they are two different questions.

Comment: @NogShine Yes. because answer would be Ganga is sacred and it gives reason in addition too. So, that's the reason i said it is subjective. And more specifically in the above example,  OP's question has exact text which is required.

Comment: Now, you agree that they are not exactly duplicates but similar. When you say, subjective, what is the site policy? I remember you saying that it is [questions and not answers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20362/what-is-the-age-limit-of-getting-a-yajnopavita-for-various-castes#comment58490_20362) which decides duplicate and " If questions are entirely different, it is suggested not to close them even though answers are same. See this meta Post “Close as duplicate” - what if only the answer is a duplicate?"  So, I thought they are not duplicates because they ask different. @The